# PowerBI Embedded: 401 (Unauthorized) from wabi-north-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/explorations/.../cache

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I recently updated from the old Power BI embedded method to the new one. Everything works fine and the report loads but in the console I get:

```
POST https://wabi-west-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/explorations/2210976/cache 401 (Unauthorized)
```

errors. I do not know what this means and if there is something wrong in my configuration. The payload is like:

```
{"visualQueryResults":[{"visualContainerId":87590386,"...
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I expect it to be some kind of bug from PowerBI-JavaScript... but it has the issues set as non visible in github.

Comment: Same here we get this issue in production but I cannot detect any effect of this problem. In my case: POST https://wabi-west-us-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/explorations/4627385/cache 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: I'm not sure what configuration I have different but I setup our Development envrionment months ago and were not getting this error in Dev. In Production we just setup a new service account and App Registration and embedding seems to be working fine except we are getting this error now. Have not tracked down the root cause....yet. https://wabi-us-west2-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/explorations/.../cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same errors occurring in my power bi embeded reports. I reported the issue to Microsoft and it was confirmed a bug. Its not slated to be fixed until October 2019 currently. Microsoft confirmed its safe to go to Production with these errors occurring. The priority may be raised if others report this issue as well. You can report the issue if you go here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/, scroll all the way to the bottom and click "CREATE SUPPORT TICKET".

[image]

[image]