# Power-BI Embedded 401 get request that does not effect application

Tags: angular, powerbi, embedded, powerbi-embedded

I am running "powerbi-client-angular": "^2.0.1" with angular V14. In our console we are getting the error of "GET https://wabi-us-east2-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/tenantsettings/properties 401"

However this does not effect any application in our web app. The reports load as expected with no issues.

What would be the cause of this? Just mainly looking to get it off the console at this point.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369667/powerbi-embedded-401-unauthorized-from-wabi-north-europe-redirect-analysis-wi